# How can I create a HTML login that connects to a database with PHP?

Tags: php, html, authentication, xampp

I am trying to create a working HTML Login Page with a PHP script that compares the login data with the Database.
I have been trying to get this working for some time now but it doesent really work. This is the Error Code I get when I press on the Login Button:

```
Cannot POST /connectivity.php
```

I created a Database (called leftover_youth)with XAMPP.

```
UserNameID
userName
pass
```

This at the moment the HTML code for the whole page.

```
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" name="viewport">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Project Bootstrap</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
                <div class="navlogo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <h1 class="Logo">Leftover Youth</h1>
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img class="logoo" src="img/logoo.png" alt="firstimage"> 
                    </a>
                </div>
        </header>
        <div>
        <fieldset style="width:30%">
            <legend>LOG-IN HERE</legend> 
            <form method="POST" action="connectivity.php"> User <br>
                <input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br> Password <br>
                <input type="password" name="pass" size="40"><br> 
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In"> 
            </form> 
        </fieldset> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'leftover_youth'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];

function SignIn()
{
session_start(); //starting the session 
if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking User data
{ 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass']; 
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE..."; 

        } 
        else 
        { 
                echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
        } 
} 
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignIn(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: First of all, visit http://bobby-tables.com and elarn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Right now your code is really vulnerable and your whole database can be deleted in a few seconds without any need of knowledge of your system. Alwqys use prepared statements for queries with user inputs!!!! Also, stop using `mysql_*` - its deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` driver instead - they'll support prepared statements. Also google for `PHP password verify function` - never store passwords in plaintext in your database.

Comment: Better use `mysqli` and `prepared statement`

Comment: If you want to go live with your project, I really recommend you to take a loginsystem that already exists, rather than creating your own. Login Systems are a quite difficult topic if you really want to make them safe, and as I can see you don't know that much about security & the way we write PHP nowaday. Thats not an offense, I just recommend you to either learn how we query a database in 2017, learn about prepared statements or simply use a finished system. Right now I would never go live with your code, its way to unsecure.

Comment: Okay i may do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the directory/path of **connectivity.php**

also move the **$ID** and  **$Password** in to the post check

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignIn(); 
 $ID = $_POST['user'];
 $Password = $_POST['pass'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid using `mysql` which is long back deprecated, instead use `mysqli`

There are few solutions for your problem.

The way with MySQLi would be like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

To run database queries is also simple and nearly identical with the old way:

```
// Old way
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
// New way
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
```